# Vertical align centre and matching heights in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do some vertical aligning in Bootstrap and can't seem to achieve it with the various flex box classes (align-items-center etc).

I need the text content in the boxes of the below codepen to be vertically centered ... whilst also each box should match the height of the tallest box (as is currently working)... can anyone help?!

The inner divs need to be wrapped in a link - don't know if thats affecting things?

https://codepen.io/jwacreative/pen/VwjePEj

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
  <a href="http://">
    <div class="summary-box h-100" style="background:red">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
  <a href="http://">
    <div class="summary-box h-100" style="background:green">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Some text longer text Some text longer text Some text longer text Some text longer text Some text longer text Some text longer text<< /p>
    </div>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
    <div class="summary-box h-100" style="background:blue">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Grid should be able to help with this...

```
.summary-box {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Great - Ive never used 'grid' before due to compatibility so wasn't really aware of this solution - but I think in this case, the fallback of it not being vertically centered is perfectly acceptable!